# Iterate and return array of consecutive n elements

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, ienumerable

In Ruby there is an `each_cons` on [Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001515). It works like this

```
(1..5).each_cons(3) {|n| p n}
```

> [1, 2, 3]
>   [2, 3, 4]
>   [3, 4, 5]

I would like to do this in C#. LINQ would be nice.

The following does something similar but it loops one to many and it's also hardcoded to return only two elements

```
var ints = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
var cons = ints.Select((o, i) =>
            new int[]{ ints[i], i == ints.Length - 1 ? 0 : ints[i + 1] });
```

It would be nice if it could be created as an iterator over the original array instead of having to create a lot of arrays.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following

```
var ints = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(x => Enumerable.Range(x, 3));
```

This will return an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>` with the specified values.  You can add the `.ToArray` expression at any point to get it into an array if that's the intent (can't tell if that's whatthe `[]` mean in ruby)

Comment: Nice and I don't actually need to do it over unordered ranges/arrays. Not right now anyway.

Comment: @Jay: Actually is good for generic too. You just need something that generates a T from an int, then with a simple Select the job is done.

Answer (score 6):

You can create an extension method that achieves it in this way:

```
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> each_cons<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < enumerable.Count() - length + 1; i++)
        {
            yield return enumerable.Skip(i).Take(length);
        }
    }
```

Consume it:

```
var ints = Enumerable.Range(1, 7).each_cons(3);
```

Comment: If the enumerable is some kind of linked list, wouldn't the `Skip(i)` get slower by each iteration then?

Comment: @Jonas This is actually extremely fast -- between 150 and 250 times faster than the head/tail implementation you'd been using in the previous extension method you posted, and using a `LinkedList<int>` actually makes it significantly faster.

Comment: How did you measure that? I did some simple `StopWatch` tests with lists of 100000 numbers and though mine was slower it was only 12ms against 15ms.

Comment: @Jonas Don't forget to call `ToList()` or `ToArray()` on both the inner and outer `IEnumerable<T>`. Using the `yield` keyword means that execution is deferred -- there is no enumeration until the values are requested/used, but you can force evaluation by creating a list or array.

Comment: I thought I did that but I did not. Now that I did I see the HUGE speed difference.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic extension method that turned out to be way to complicated for my current use case but it seems to work.

```
static class EnumerableExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> EachCons<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int cons)
    {
        for (IEnumerable<T> head = sequence.Take(cons), tail = sequence.Skip(1);
             head.Count() == cons; head = tail.Take(cons), tail = tail.Skip(1))
             yield return head;
    }
}
```

**Use Jay's implementation instead. It's MUCH faster. I just left this one here because it's mentioned in Jay's answer.**